# How to combine a choice form-type with an type=integer assertion

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, constraints, assert

I have a field called 'inclination' that takes integers from 0 to 90 (degrees).
In the assert statement I state that the type must be integer.

In this case I would like to render the field as a choice-widget, a drop-down list with values ranging from 0 to 90.
I can't, however, find a way to let the selection happen as integer. Every time I try to submit the form, the error 'this field must be of type Integer' shows up.

Is there any way to:
**let the combination of a drop-down choice list and an assert\Type(type="Integer")**
work?

The definition of the **property** in the entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="inclination", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Min(limit=0)
     * @Assert\Max(limit=90)
     * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
     */
    private $inclination;
```

The way the **field** in the form gets built:

```
$builder->add('inclination', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $this->getInclinationChoices(), 
            'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
            ));

private function getInclinationChoices()
    {
        $choices = array();
        for($i=0; $i<= 90; $i++) {
            $choices[$i] = "$i °"; 
        }
        return $choices;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if its the proper Symfony 2 approach, but could you force the value to a PHP integer type on the Entity's `setInclination()` method?

Eg:

```
public function setInclination($inclination)
{
    $this->inclination = (int) $inclination;
}
```

I recreated your issue locally and this fix worked for me.

Comment: That might work, thanks for the advice. When I get around to refactoring, I'm going to try it out.
For now I'm setting it as the answer, since it worked for you locally.

Comment: It worked for me and it gave me the desired results. But I still feel that there may be a better Symfony-friendly way to do this (a form validation group perhaps). I just haven't found it yet. Hoping someone with more Symfony experience has an alternative solution to share with us.